# Dreamweaver CS6

Tags: mysql, dreamweaver

Can anybody figure this out?

HTTP Error Code 404 File Not Found. Here are some possible reasons for the problem:

1) There is no testing server running on the server machine.
2) The testing server specified for this site does not map to the http://www.oneforestfilms.com/_mmServerScripts/MMHTTPDB.php URL. Verify that the URL Prefix maps to the root of the site.

I cannot get any farther on to connect to my xampp server and mySQL database

Dreamweaver seems to be the one having problems. It's not the web host or the MySQL database. It's Dreamweaver. I've tried this in both CS5.5 and CS6 and get the same error message in both. What should I do? How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The address you are using:

```
http://www.oneforestfilms.com/_mmServerScripts/MMHTTPDB.php
```

This domains DNS does not resolve, so Dreamweaver will not be able to access/find it, which is why it's giving you a 404.

Comment: What should I change it to then? the other website i was working on gives this error...  http://localhost/Golfbuddies/_mmServerScripts/MMHTTPDB.phpURL. Verify that the URL Prefix maps to the root of the site

Comment: do you have a webserver setup on local host?  if not this will never work

Comment: Yes I have Apache webserver setup on localhost but this keeps coming up  when I put the MySQL connection into dreamweaver